# Is it possible to include a log statement in Drools rule or function

Tags: drools

Let's say I have a function to check if a certain object is invalid in Drools.
I call this function from a rule when a certain set of conditions are satisfied. If the function returns true, then I retract the message from drools.

Can we add log statements in drools functions or rules?

E.g.

```
rule "Validate abc"
dialect "mvel"
no-loop
salience 3
    when
        eval(validateABC(...))
    then
        /* log something here */
        retract...
end

function boolean validateABC(...) {
 check for certain conditions and have log statements 
 if the conditions are satisfied
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply try it and see what happens? The book says that right hand side code is written using Java, and so is a function body.

Comment: @laune Maybe the real question here is how to add a logger such as Log4j to Drools working memory and do it efficiently? And are there some specific logging frameworks more suitable to Drools?

Comment: @kaskelotti If it is, it should be asked.